# Samsung Note 1 - cut or copy in any app causes it to hang and crash

Tags: crashes, copy-paste

I hope someone can help rather than the normal suggestion of rebuild.

I have Samsung Note 1 with Android 4.0.4. This is the most up to date version available (UK - O2 network)

Cut or copy hangs the application. This is the same across all apps.

Any suggestions as its almost impossible to use without it as I use it as my main business tool.

Comment: I assume you've turned the thing off and back on. Have you tried a Force Stop on "Android system" or "Android keyboard"? Maybe "System UI"?

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset yet?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [clipboard-related Samsung firmware bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35732) which is known at least since July 2012 and happens on multiple Samsung devices with Android 4.0.x (ICS). It is reported to be fixed in Jelly Bean updates, but they may not be available for all devices which have this problem. Other solutions discussed in the bug comments, such as removing everything from the `/data/clipboard` directory, require a rooted phone.

The bug is also not present in custom ROMs which are not based on Samsung TouchWiz (such as CyanogenMod).

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Note stores everything from the clipboard. I would imagine that months of old clipboard items may cause a problem eventually. You might try to double-tap a text field, select Clipboard and delete old clipboard entries from there.

Comment: Good idea. I would think it would scroll out (delete old cut and pastes). However worth a check. How do I "long press and select clipboard. Does not seem to be available on Icecream. Any manual way of checking out the clip board. Please?

Comment: @MindBody I made an error: in a text field you double tap (not long tap as my post says) to bring up the option for clipboard. Samsung phones specifically extend the clipboard functionality to include a history where you can select older items. I don't think this is available in non-Samsung phones out of the box.